# Register type per lifetime of another object

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I'm looking for an IoC container which is able to do the following:

1. Suppose I have an object which is accessible via AmbientContext, something like `LifetimeProvider.Current`.
2. Suppose I have a type which is to be resolved at some point inside the application, something like `IDependency` and `Dependency`.
3. I want to have different instances of `IDependency` when the value of `LifetimeProvider.Current` changes.
4. I want to have `IDependency` value of `null` when the value of `LifetimeProvider.Current` is null.

Is that possible?

P.S. Below is the test that should pass for case 4):

```
[Test]
// Given There Is Lifetime Provider
// When Dependency Is Registered Per Lifetime And Lifetime Provider Becomes Null
// Then Dependency Becomes Null
public void Test()
{                        
    var container = new SuperDuperContainer();
    container.RegisterPerLifetime(
        () => LifetimeProvider.Current, typeof(IDependency), null, typeof(Dependency));
    var @object = string.Empty;
    LifetimeProvider.Current = @object;
    container.GetInstance(typeof (IDependency), null);            
    LifetimeProvider.Current = null;
    var dependency = container.GetInstance(typeof (IDependency), null);
    Assert.IsNull(dependency);
}
```

Comment: What's completely missing from your question is *why* you require this behavior. What use case and design do you have that requires this behavior?

Comment: Note that your question is off-topic for Stackoverflow, because you are asking for a "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

Comment: I wouldn't say it's off-topic. It's a development question for a problem in hand.
That said, the use case is the following:
I have a client desktop app which contains an instance of ```IDataService``` internally. This is a representation of models used throughout the application. This interface is injected into several places and has a lifetime of singleton.
It's resolved after the user logs into the system and should be released after they log out.

Comment: That means the next time the IDataService is resolved it should be a new clean instance

Comment: @GenaVerdel - So, what you are saying is that you have *runtime behavior* (logging in and out) that you are somehow trying to tie directly to your DI container. It sounds like what you want to do is cache something and invalidate the cache when the user logs out - that is not a DI container's job - you should use design patterns *within your application* to solve this.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Thanks for pointing out a way of achieving the functionality.
Why is this approach different from nested/child lifetime scopes? 
In a way this lifetime provider is a lifetime scope originator, isn't it?
I mean how is this lifetime style different from having dependencies bound to a session/http context variables?

Comment: @GenaVerdel - This is like asking whether it is appropriate to pound in a nail with a wrench. It might work, but it is not what it is designed to do. DI containers are for *application configuration*. They are the glue that holds the application together. But it is a separate concern from any of the *business logic* within the application. It is helpful to ask yourself frequently `will I be able to swap DI container A for B if I do this?`, if the answer is no, you are probably creating direct coupling to the DI container from your application.

Comment: Thanks. You haven't added any new information. All these questions have been asked already. Best of luck, @NightOwl888